# Unbounded Function Becomes Bounded through Polar Transformation?

Tags: calculus, integral-transforms

$D=\{(x,y)|5x^2+6y^2\leq1\}$

$\int\int_D \frac{x^2}{(5x^2+6y^2)^\frac3 2}$

The integrand is not bounded. When performing a polar transformation for the ellipse domain the integrand becomes bounded since the Jacobean is $\frac{1}{\sqrt40}r$:

$\frac{1}{\sqrt 40} cos^2(\theta)$

I was wondering what is the reason for that and if there is an intuitive way of understanding this transformation.

Comment: why is the integrand "not bounded"?

Comment: I think the integrand is not bounded over the domain since $\frac{x^2}{(5x^2+6y^2)^{3/2}}\leq\frac{1}{5^{3/2}}\frac{1}{|x|}.$